# mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'ext4'

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I am trying to install Arch Linux on VirtualBox, however, when I am trying to mount the filesystems I get an error:  'unknown filesystem type ext4'.

I know there is a lot of people ran into the same problem and there's plenty of information available on the net but I can't seem to find a solution.

the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Root@archiso ~ fdisk –l
Disk /dev/sda: 64GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x17c5711e
Device           Boot           Start          End              Sectors           Size                Id               Type
/dev/sda1        *               2048        411647            409600             200M              83              Linux
/dev/sda2                       411648     8603647            8192000            3.9G               82          Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3                    8603648      134217727           125614080             59.9.G          83         Linux

Disk /dev/loop0: 403 MiB, 422539264 bytes, 825272 sectors
```

The error I get when I run `mount /dev/sda3 /mnt`:

```
mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'ext4'.
```

By the way, how can I copy the contents of a command from VirtualBox Arch installer? I copied it the hard way! the mouse is invisible inside the ZSH and I can't use redirection > in order to save the contents as no filesystem is mounted.

Thanks.

Comment: What archiso image are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Encountered the same problem with Arch guest on Virtualbox, solved by booting into live media, chrooting again into installed system:

```
# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
# arch-chroot /mnt
```

and reinstalling the kernel:

```
# pacman -S linux
```

Not sure why ext4 module gets removed, though.

Comment: As for copying the text from terminal, have you tried to install the [GPM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/console_mouse_support) package? That would enable the mouse support in native terminals, but, unfortunately, not in the emergency terminal. Also, you will need the [Virtualbox Additions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Installation_steps_for_Arch_Linux_guests) for the shared clipboard.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me on a system that I've been using as my daily workstation for months.  I had done some updates via `packer -Syu` like I always do, and somehow it couldn't mount my ext4 /boot, and was stuck at an emergency shell at boot time.  The fix steps in this answer worked for me, only substituting my own device names instead of sda1,2 since I use MD Raid for my /boot.